# Bug in ListVectorPlot?

Tags: plotting, version-8

Trying to evaluate the following expression kills my kernel (Mathematica 8.0.0.0):

```
ListVectorPlot[{{{0.04039190555`,0.00897597901`},{0.1094840396`,-0.4878660114`}},{{0.01346396852`,-0.02692793703`},{-0.4484770638`,-0.2210618086`}},{{-0.01346396852`,0.02692793703`},{0.4484771099`,0.2210617151`}},{{0.04039190555`,0},{6.015064858999999`*^-7,-0.5`}},{{-0.04039190555`,0},{-8.376467958999999`*^-7,0.5`}},{{0.04039190555`,0.004487989505`},{0.05578099204`,-0.4968787387`}},{{0.04039190555`,-0.004487989505`},{-0.0557801133`,-0.4968788373`}},{{-0.04039190555`,-0.004487989505`},{-0.05578124893`,0.4968787098`}},{{-0.04039190555`,0.004487989505`},{0.05577990379`,0.4968788608`}},
{{0.03141592654`,0.004487989505`},{0.0717709292`,-0.4948221233`}}
}]
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: Works for me on 9.0.1 Windows.

Comment: It quits the kernel and doesn't output anything on _v8.0.4_.

Comment: Also works fine for me, running V9.0.1 on OS X,

Comment: It works at first on v10.0.2 on Windows 7 (64 Bit) but crashes if called again.

Answer (score 4):

Still crashes the kernel in version 10.0.2. The reason seems to be that the points don't lie on a regular grid: The command

```
ListVectorPlot[
 Table[{{x, -y}, {-y, x}}, {x, -3, 3, 0.5}, {y, -3, 3, 0.5}], VectorPoints -> All]
```

works, but the command

```
ListVectorPlot[
 Table[{{x, -y + 0.01*x}, {-y, x}}, {x, -3, 3, 0.5}, {y, -3, 3, 0.5}], VectorPoints -> All]
```

crashes the second or third time it's called.
Ron

Comment: I verified it. Same on my machine, 10.0.1

Comment: Same on 10.0.2 and Win 7 (64 Bit)

Comment: Verified also, 10.0.0.0 Linux x86 (64-bit) Ubuntu 18.04.4

Answer (score 0):

[image]

MMA 10.0.1 X64 Win7.

Works fine. Glad it did not crash!

Comment: But did you try to do it repeatedly? v10.0.2 crashes the second or third time it is called on Wind 7 (64 Bit).

Comment: In 10.0.1 X64 (Win7), I repeated 3 times. It was fine.